# Print out from specific string to rest of line in text file

Tags: grep

I have a log file. The file consists of several total times recorded, "TOTAL TIME TAKEN: 84848" at the end of a script run. I am trying to pull out this specific piece of information so I can see which script is taking the longest to run. This portion also is how the line ends. There is nothing after the number. So the desired output would be the following:

```
TOTAL TIME TAKEN: xxxxx
TOTAL TIME TAKEN: xxx
TOTAL TIME TAKEN: xxxx
and so on...
```

Using grep I am able to print to screen all the lines containing the above string. But I am only interested in the above part. Using '-o' option, I only get 'TOTAL TIME TAKEN:' portion without the number. So my question is, is there a way to print to screen everything from the desired string ("TOTAL TIME TAKEN:") to the rest of the line.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

grep -o 'TIME TAKEN: [0-9]{1,}' logFile